# Crash when using matrices as vertex shader attributes

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertex-shader

I'm trying to create an OpenGL vertex shader that has an additional transformation matrix for each vertex. My shader code looks like this:

```
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

attribute vec3 coordinates;
attribute mat4 vertexTransformation;
attribute vec4 vertexColor;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() 
{
    vec4 pos = vec4( coordinates, 1 );

    pos = vertexTransformation * pos;
    pos = mvpMatrix * pos;
    gl_Position = pos;

    v_color = color;
}
```

Whenever I execute this in the android emulator, the emulator crashes.

I tried to isolate the problem and found that it happens, whenever I access the `vertexTransformation` attribute. The following code also results in a crash, even if there are no further matrix operations involved.

```
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

attribute vec3 coordinates;
attribute mat4 vertexTransformation;
attribute vec4 vertexColor;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() 
{
    vec4 pos = vec4( coordinates, 1 );

    pos = mvpMatrix * pos;
    gl_Position = pos;

    vec4 col = vec4( 0,0,0,1 );
    if ( vertexTransformation[0][0] == 0.5 )
        v_color = color;
    else
        v_color = vec4( 1, 1, 1, 1 );    
}
```

I'm using `glBufferData` to pass the data:

```
ByteBuffer vertexData = ...;
vertexData.position( 0 );

GLES20.glBufferData( GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData.remaining(), vertexData, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

and then bind the attributes with

```
int handle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation( programId, "vertexTransformation" );
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray( handle );
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer( handle, 16, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 92, 28 );
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to provide matrix attributes to a vertex and use them in the vertex shader?

Comment: how do you pass the attribute in the shader?

Comment: ByteBuffer vertexData = ...;
 vertexData.position( 0 );

 GLES20.glBufferData( GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData.remaining(), vertexData, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW );

Comment: I mean the glVertexAttribPointer calls ([add them to the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27091599/edit))

Comment: How many vertex attribute arrays do you have setup? A `mat4` vertex attribute is equivalent to 4 `vec4`s and should have 4 separate attribute pointers (N,N+1,N+2,N+3) where `N` is the attribute location for "vertexTransformation". It is quite possible that you don't have the other 3 arrays (N+1 through N+3) setup with a valid state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This blurb of code is wrong:

```
int handle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation( programId, "vertexTransformation" );
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray( handle );
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer( handle, 16, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 92, 28 );
```

Vertex attributes in OpenGL are always 4-component, thus a `mat4` vertex attribute is actually 4 sequential 4-component arrays.

#### This is the proper way of handling a `mat4` vertex attribute:

```
int handle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation( programId, "vertexTransformation" );

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray( handle );
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer( handle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 92, 28 );

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray( handle + 1 );
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer( handle + 1, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 92, 28+16 );

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray( handle + 2 );
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer( handle + 2, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 92, 28+32 );

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray( handle + 3 );
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer( handle + 3, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 92, 28+48 );
```

Notice how it requires 4 vertex attribute pointers? The vertex attribute "vertexTransformation" actually occupies locations `handle` through `handle+3`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try that. But if you say that vertex-attributes are allways 4 components, why does the **coordinates** vector work, since I pass only 3 values there?

Comment: Well, you only give it enough values for 3 of the 4-components. That doesn't change the way that vertex attributes work behind the scenes. In that scenario, the `w` component is automatically assigned a value of **1.0**. This is why it is often handy to write vertex position attributes as `vec4` in the vertex shader; if you understand what OpenGL does in this situation, you won't have to write `vec4( coordinates, 1 )` anymore. _The automatic assignment of **1.0** to `w` only works for `w`, for any other missing component GL automatically assigns **0.0**._